# Permission Error when try running the selenium with python script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

```
CustomerPortalApp\TestCases\conftest.py:20: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py:40: in install  
    driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver) C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py:41: in _get_driver_binary_path
    binary_path = self._cache_manager.save_file_to_cache(driver, file) C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py:54: in save_file_to_cache
    files = self.unpack_archive(archive, path) C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py:49: in unpack_archive
    return self._file_manager.unpack_archive(archive, path) C:\Users\deepika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\file_manager.py:57: in unpack_archive
    return self.__extract_zip(archive_file, target_dir)
```

---

```
self = <webdriver_manager.core.file_manager.FileManager object at 0x000001AF5DEF88E0>
archive_file = <webdriver_manager.core.archive.Archive object at 0x000001AF5DEFB8B0>
to_directory = 'C:\\Users\\.wdm\\drivers\\chromedriver\\win64\\120.0.6099.71'

    def __extract_zip(self, archive_file, to_directory):
        zip_class = (LinuxZipFileWithPermissions if self._os_system_manager.get_os_name() == "linux" else zipfile.ZipFile)
        archive = zip_class(archive_file.file_path)
        try:
            archive.extractall(to_directory)
        except Exception as e:
            if e.args[0] not in [26, 13] and e.args[1] not in [
                "Text file busy",
                "Permission denied",
            ]:
                raise e
            file_names = []
            for n in archive.namelist():
                if "/" not in n:
                    file_names.append(n)
                else:
                    file_path, file_name = n.split("/")
                    full_file_path = os.path.join(to_directory, file_path)
                    source = os.path.join(full_file_path, file_name)
                    destination = os.path.join(to_directory, file_name)
```

> ```
>               os.replace(source, destination)
> ```

```
E                   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\.wdm\\drivers\\chromedriver\\win64\\120.0.6099.71\\chromedriver-win32\\chromedriver.exe' -> 'C:\\Users\\.wdm\\drivers\\chromedriver\\win64\\120.0.6099.71\\chromedriver.exe'

C:\Users\deepika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\file_manager.py:81: PermissionError
```

I need a solution to fix this error